# jsf 2 url in css using el resource

Tags: jsf-2, el

Should I be able to use EL in css to access an img in the resources folder of a jsf 2 app?  It does not seems to be working.  In my css I've below:

```
.sectionDivider {
    background-image: "#{resource['default:img/dashes.png']}"; 
    background-position:center; 
    width:100%; 
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    height: 1px; 
    overflow: hidden;
```

}

When I access the page thru the browser, the background-image is not showing.  When I view the CSS using browser Developer tools, the CSS looks like below (The background-image is missing):

```
.sectionDivider {
WIDTH: 100%; BACKGROUND-REPEAT: repeat-x; BACKGROUND-POSITION: center 50%; HEIGHT: 1px; OVERFLOW: hidden
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I forgot to put url() in the background-image style.  I changed to do below and it is working now:

```
.sectionDivider {
    background-image: url('#{resource['default:img/dashes.png']}'); 
    background-position:center; 
    width:100%; 
    background-repeat: repeat-x; 
    height: 1px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```